# Power of trig functions integrations

Tags: integration

[image]

Not really sure how it went from 1 da to 3/2 a (from 3rd line to 4th line)

Comment: There is a picture in the post

Comment: $1 + \frac 1 2 = \frac 3 2$. Also, it's generally a good idea to put an image description in the part that says "enter image description here."

Comment: In the third line there was a $1$ early and a $\frac{1}{2}$ later.  They got combined in the fourth line.

Comment: That came from the u-sub right?

Comment: The $1$ and the later $\frac{1}{2}$ came from the double angle formula for cosine.

Answer (score 2):

The constants are summed up from separate terms.

$$ 1 + \frac12 = \frac32$$